# Pyqt5 почему не работает show()

Tags: python, pyqt5

Вот события `keyPressEvent()`. Если мы нажимаем клавишу `Esc`, то приложение `hide()`.

А теперь я хочу нажать `alt` и чтобы оно `show()`, но оно не работает. Помогите

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Event handler')
        self.show()

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.hide()
        elif e.key() == Qt.Key_Alt:
            self.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Example()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: что то мне подсказывает, что вы не то закрываете

Comment: Я скинул полный код

Answer (score 1):

> `Key events` отправляются в виджет `с фокусом ввода` с клавиатуры при нажатии или отпускании клавиш.
>
> https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html#details
>
> **Внимание! - с фокусом ввода !**

Вставьте какой-нибудь `print('QtCore.Qt.Key_Alt')` и нажимайте `alt`
Вы видите работу принта.

Теперь сверните выше окно и нажимайте `alt`.
Ничего не происходит, т.к. приложение не в фокусе.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Event handler')
        self.show()

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.hide()
        elif e.key() == Qt.Key_Alt:
            print('QtCore.Qt.Key_Alt')                  # +++
            self.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Example()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**Update**

То что вы задумали, может быть реализовано с дочерним виджетом, 
например так см. пример 2. При этом если главное окно в фокусе.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Event handler')

        self.label = QLabel('Hello World', self)            # +++
        self.label.move(100, 50)                            # +++

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.label.hide()                               # self.label
        elif e.key() == Qt.Key_Alt:
            print('QtCore.Qt.Key_Alt')                 
            self.label.show()                               # self.label


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Example()
ex.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Максим скажите пожалуйста, вы с данным вопросом разобрались или нет ?